# empty box wont resize responsively correctly

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am creating a responsive template. Most of the page contains images that resize nicely.

However there is one box that is empty that I want to resize in proportion to the images.

However, when I move into the smaller screen sizes the width responds well but the box collapses to have no height.

I realise that I could use some jQ to get the height required but that seems like using a hammer to crack a nut.

Here's the css

```
/*full width*/
.moduletable_homeSMPosition007
width: 213px;
height: 119px;
background-color:#E9ABAF;
border:1px solid #d1d3d4;

/*inside a media query*/
.moduletable_homeSMPosition007 {
box-sizing:border-box;
max-width:48%;
height:auto;
width: auto\9;
}
```

Comment: maybe you can add some kind of minimum height that is equal to the smallest size possible on screens.

Comment: yes, i could but then the empty box wont line up correctly with the others.